# Ensure nothing is on an SD card after main system it was on was infected by CTB-Locker

Tags: windows-7, virus, sd-card, format

My parent’s computer—which is running Windows 7—got infected by [CTB-Locker](https://www.f-secure.com/weblog/archives/00002788.html), an SD card was attached too so it got corrupted as well. I want to remove everything from the SD card, does a simple format ensure the corruption is no longer there? How can I check that the card is fully clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading up [on the details of CTB-Locker](http://malwareprotectioncenter.com/2015/02/06/ctb-locker/), it seems like the main way the CTB-Locker affects a system is via per-file encryption. I assume then that if the main system is cleaned or even reformatted, then formatting the SD card should be a safe bet.

But on the off-chance this malware operates on some deeper file system level—one where the malware might sit dormant on the SD card, waiting to infect later—then I would recommend you repartition as well as reformat the card to ensure it’s really wiped clean. For that I would recommend booting from a Linux live CD/USB of some sort—such as Ubuntu [as explained here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31804/the-10-cleverest-ways-to-use-linux-to-fix-your-windows-pc/)—and wiping the SD card from that Linux live CD/USB as the safest bet.

Remember, viruses and malware are insidious but are *always* OS specific. And that OS specificity is pretty much *always* based on Windows. So by booting into a Linux live CD/USB you ensure that you will be on a neutered system—as far as running Windows programming/coding is concerned—to safely clean up and wipe off that mess from the SD card or any other mounted Windows device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a format should be enough. However you could use the [Free Dr.Web utility](https://news.drweb.com/show/?i=5962&lng=en) to attempt to restore files encrypted by `Android.Locker.2.origin` ransomware.

> After thoroughly examining the ransomware, Doctor Web designed a
>   special utility that will most likely decrypt files corrupted by the
>   malicious application, making it unnecessary for users to pay a
>   ransom.
>
> The utility scans the available SD card for encrypted files and
>   attempts to restore one of them as a test. If successful, the program
>   starts restoring all the corrupted files it has found. Backups of all
>   the corrupted files are placed in the directory DrWebTemp before the
>   utility attempts to decrypt them. All the recovered files are restored
>   to their original location and the extension .enc is removed from
>   their filenames. To avoid permanent data loss after the utility
>   finishes its work, the directory DrWebTemp, which contains copies of
>   the encrypted files, is not removed.

EDIT 1
As per [Andrew Morton's Comment](https://superuser.com/questions/887891/ensure-nothing-is-on-an-sd-card-after-main-system-it-was-on-was-infected-by-ctb/887897?noredirect=1#comment1186411_887897),

> It appears that the Dr.Web utility is only free if you already have a
>   licence for other software from them: "Please note that the decryption
>   service is only available to users who have purchased commercial
>   licenses for Doctor Web anti-viruses. To get the utility, you have to
>   be an owner of a commercial Dr.Web for Android, Dr.Web Security Space
>   or Dr.Web Anti-virus license which includes technical support."

Comment: It appears that the Dr.Web utility is only free if you already have a licence for other software from them: "Please note that the decryption service is only available to users who have purchased commercial licenses for Doctor Web anti-viruses. To get the utility, you have to be an owner of a commercial Dr.Web for Android, Dr.Web Security Space or Dr.Web Anti-virus license which includes technical support."

Comment: once I reinstalled Windows on my machine witout backup everything, so I had to use a tool to find the missing files. The data is only unrefernced but still there. Are you sure formatting makes the card safe?